# Before update trigger is not creating history for null values

Tags: oracle

My before update trigger is not creating any history for changing null value to any other value. It is creating history for changing any other values.
My main logic is like this:

```
if nvl(:old.place,null) <> nvl(:new.place,null) then
    insert into table (place)
    values(:old.place)
end if;
```

Comment: Your problem is that the comparison `'any value' <> null` is always false, as is this one: `'any value' = null`. You should use `IS NULL` for null comparison.

Answer (score 0):

[The `NVL()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions119.htm) is used to substitute a value in place of null. You're replacing null with... null, which is pointless. You're then trying to compare two null values with the (in)equality operator, and as null is neither equal to or not equal to anything including itself, the result is unknown, and your condition is always false if either the old or new value is null.

You could use a fixed dummy value that you know will never actually exit:

```
if nvl(:old.place,'**fake**') <> nvl(:new.place,'**fake**') then
```

But for clarity I'd generally prefer to explicitly test for nulls:

```
if (:old.place is null and :new.place is not null)
  or (:old.place is not null and :new.place is null)
  or (:old.place != :new.place) then
```